# python 2: computing large powers vs their mods

Tags: python-2.7, modulo, largenumber

In Python 2.7, computing a large power such as:

```
2**7830457
```

takes a very long time. However, taking the modulo of a large power:

```
(2**7830457) % 10**10
```

computes almost instantly. Why is this?

Comment: That's really interesting, I don't know. I guess the modulo somehow prevents the `(2**7830457) ` from being computed in full before acting. Would really like to see someone's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delay seen when computing `2**7830457` is not a result of the computation but of the time it takes the terminal to buffer and print the result.

As a result:

```
a = 2**7830457 #instant 
print a  #as slow as running 2**7830457
```